# Problem with PHP server

Tags: php, function

I'm having some problems with my PHP server. Most of the functions when run gives the same error.

```
Warning: fopen(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2475.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a 
period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. D:\inetpub\vhosts\coolfbapps.in\httpdocs\test\merger2.php on line 3

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\inetpub\vhosts\coolfbapps.in\httpdocs\test\merger2.php on line 3
```

The same error comes when i use imagecreate functions, get_image functions.

I talked to service providers but they said I should tell them the cause of this error so that they can rectify it. Please se if any one can make out what changes should be done to server to remove those errors.

**CODE USED**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/95111e2f99bb4b277764c76ad9ad3569?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");
$fp = fopen("http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2475.txt", "r");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You need to have a look at the `in --` areas. Post the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this, but I'm unable to comment yet. You need to post the code that is causing these errors. Are you explicitly requesting that URL?

To debug this, you should logon to the server and attempt to request the file to see if you're actually able to have outbound connections on port 80. To do this on a linux server just run

```
wget http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2475.txt
```

.. and see if it fails or not. If it does, you need to talk to your hosting provider / ISP.

If you don't have access to the server you could simply try (in PHP):

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/'); // Google so that it's not the same URL
?>
```

If there's an error, same as above.

Comment: I have already tried it. file_get_contents gives the same error. Pls see the code i just updated

Comment: If that doesn't work (even with Google?) then it's definitely a hosting issue.

Comment: yes gives the same error with google. Now what should I tell the service providers? They told me to tell where the problem is. i have already told them that those functions are not working.

Comment: The functions & PHP itself are working fine, you need to tell them that you're not able to connect to external HTTP servers. Give them the example of `file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');`, if they don't know what the problem is from there, I'd consider switching providers.

Comment: they said they don't allow outbound connections on port 80. i'm using windows hosting..

Comment: Haha, really? In that case, you **need** to change provider. That's a very stupid restriction, even moreso if they won't give you exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

The first error (the fopen() one) is caused because of a timeout in the response of the server you're trying to load the data from. i.e. the server is taking too long to respond, so the connection times out.

The second error is that the script is running for too long. PHP has a setting called max_execution_time so that a script can't eat up all the resources on a server. Your server has a setting to allow 30 seconds to execute, or die() with a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your server can't connect to these sites. Perhaps your server is not allowed to start outgoing connections or is blocking that outgoing HTTP traffic somehow?

I bet this isn't a PHP problem but instead has to do with your server connection. If you have SSH access, try to open these URLs from the command line without PHP.